# Distribution of Mass through the Higgs Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, photons, higgs

How does the Higgs Field distribute mass to particles? I am aware that it is through distributing weak hypercharge but am confused as to what distinguishes a photon and an electron to the Higgs Field. Both possess spin and the capability to travel at light speed yet somehow only an electron is given mass and effected by this field.  So in total how does the Higgs Field decide what to interact with or what keeps the Higgs Field from interacting with photons per se or other massless particles?

Comment: Bdically the decision of  how to distribute the mass depends on  the SU(2)xU(1) structure  and the representations where the elementary particles have a niche.

Answer (score 2):

> what keeps the Higgs Field from interacting with photons per se

In the electroweak theory, the B boson (the gauge quanta of the U(1) weak hypercharge interaction), and the W bosons (the three gauge quanta of the SU(2) weak isospin interaction) *do* interact with the Higgs vacuum condensate.

However, there is specific combination of the B boson and neutral W boson that propagates freely in the condensate; this combination is the physical (observable) photon.

See, for example, the [relevant Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#The_photon_as_the_part_that_remains_massless) of the the "Higgs mechanism" article

> This combination of generators (a z rotation in the SU(2) and a
>   simultaneous U(1) rotation by half the angle) preserves the vacuum,
>   and defines the unbroken gauge group in the standard model, namely the
>   electric charge group. The part of the gauge field in this direction
>   stays massless, and amounts to the physical photon.